# UIView that creates a sub UIView is generating hierarchy constraint warnings

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, tangram

I am trying to create a TGMapView inside of my UIView. As soon as the TMMapView is created I get this error:

```
2019-02-04 14:47:22.288241-0500 IOSDemoApp[8325:289276] [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000015f0b40 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fe52fc0e750.leading == TrimbleMaps.TMMapView:0x7fe52fc0e320.leading   (inactive)>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2019-02-04 14:47:22.288477-0500 IOSDemoApp[8325:289276] [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000015f0c80 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fe52fc0e750.top == TrimbleMaps.TMMapView:0x7fe52fc0e320.top   (inactive)>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2019-02-04 14:47:22.288642-0500 IOSDemoApp[8325:289276] [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000015f0e10 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fe52ff05670.leading == TrimbleMaps.TMMapView:0x7fe52fc0e320.leading   (inactive)>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2019-02-04 14:47:22.310967-0500 IOSDemoApp[8325:289276] [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000015f0f00 TrimbleMaps.TMMapView:0x7fe52fc0e320.bottom == _UILayoutGuide:0x7fe52ff05670.bottom   (inactive)>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
```

It doesn't seem to matter that the UIView that I'm trying to create here is a TGMapView. If I try to create a plain old UIView I get the same problem.

```
public class Sample: UIView {

    private var tangramMapView: TGMapView!
    public var trivialView: UIView!

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // both have the same warning/error
        guard let tangramMapView = TGMapView(coder: aDecoder) else { return nil }
        trivialView = UIView.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()
    }
}
```

When I run this, both the TGMapView and UIView inits emit the same warnings (copied above). I expect there to be no warnings and that the UIViews constraints are handled in `setup()`. I add subviews and set constraints in `setup()`.

Is there something special about adding UIViews *to* UIViews that I don't know about? Did I do it in the wrong order? Can it not be done before the superView init is done?

EDIT:

> Why are you initializing it with Sample views' aDecoder?

No idea. I have it set up in the storyboard and I've set the View in my single view application to be a `Sample` view. In the debugger I can see that the `aDecoder` init is being called. I couldn't tell you why the others aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my question for future users and/or myself when I forget the answer in 2 months.

`init?(coder)` is used to create your UIView when your UIView is set up in storyboard. The UIView is packaged up and must be decoded. Importantly the `coder` is only for the UIView that was set up in the storyboard. In this case, that's `Sample`. Therefor it makes no sense to use `coder` to init a TGMapView or any other kind of UIView. That's the problem I was having.

The Solution? In my case, I used `init(frame)` to create any UIView that I wanted inside the view's `init?(coder)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is ok to add your contains in your init.

The issue you are facing is about the when to add constraints is a relation to subviews.

When specifying constraints between views, they must be subviews of each other (One on top of the other) or both be subviews of the same view (A different view).

And this is exacly what your error is saying:

```
 The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000015f0c80 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fe52fc0e750.top == TrimbleMaps.TMMapView:0x7fe52fc0e320.top   (inactive)>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
```

You are trying to specify **TMMapView** top constraint relation to a view that is not yet It's relative.

First **AddSubviews** ,then specify constraints.

**EDIT**

Why are you initializing it with 'Sample' views aDecoder? You should do that only when subclassing

Comment: I add subviews and set constraints in `setup()`. These warnings are happening when the UIView is created, before I even have a chance to `addsubview` or set constraints. I don't think that that is the problem.

Comment: @GranolaGuy Edited my answer. And please show 'TGMapView' init function too, it sounds relevant

Comment: TGMapView.mm can be found here:
https://github.com/tangrams/tangram-es/blob/master/platforms/ios/framework/src/TGMapView.mm

I don't think it is the problem. Remember that `UIView.init(coder: aDecoder)` causes the same problems. You could comment out one or the other have have the same issue.

Comment: @GranolaGuy You are padding the wrong aDecoder, even if you have a different issue, your UI will not work correctly before you remove this code. You must not call init with code directly not from a superclass. And I seem you are missing code in your question if that is the case

Comment: After googling all day today, I think I understand why it doesn't make sense to pass the `aDecoder` to create a new UIView in the init?(coder). The problem then becomes, how to create a UIView every time the Sample class is constructed. Do it in layoutSubviews?

Comment: @GranolaGuy Are you asking what is the correct init? If so, you should probably use initWithFrame or just init (If exists)